# Async wait block Main UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

I am using the new async await features to upgrade from backgroundworker in C#. In the following code I am trying to replicate the execution of multiple tasks with ContinueWith method.

```
        Task t1 = new Task
        (
            () =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                // make the Task throw an exception
                MessageBox.Show("This is T1");
            }
        );

        Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith
        (
            (predecessorTask) =>
            {

                if (predecessorTask.Exception != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Predecessor Exception within Continuation");

                    return;
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MessageBox.Show("This is Continuation");
            },

            TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
        );

        t1.Start();

        try
        {
           t1.Wait(); <------ Comment 
           t2.Wait(); <------ Comment 
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
```

My question is when I comment t1.wait and t2.wait Tasks are not blocking UI. However when I uncomment t1.wait and t2.wait UI blocks until thread is completed. The desired behavior is to catch errors in try/catch block without blocking UI. What Am I missing?

Comment: It blocks because you're telling it to...

Comment: well how can i not block the ui and still get wait in try/catch block.

Comment: How exactly are you hoping to throw an exception here? I can't see where one would happen..

Comment: “I am using the new async await features” Where? I don't see them anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is running within a UI event handler, you can add the `async` modifer to the method signature and change `t1.Wait()` to `await t1`. This will return control to the UI thread, and when the Thread.Sleep has completed, the continuation will execute and any exceptions will be caught.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `Task.Wait()`, you are basically saying "wait here my task to complete". That's why you are blocking the thread. A good way to handle exception in tasks is using the `Task.ContinueWith` overload and pass `OnlyOnFaulted` as `TaskContinuationOption` which would look like:

```
Task yourTask = new Task {...};
yourTask.ContinueWith( t=> { /*handle expected exceptions*/ }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx), then you should use the recommended guidelines. I have an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) describing many of them.

In particular:

- Use `Task.Run` instead of the `Task` constructor with `Task.Start`.
- Use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.
- Do not use `AttachedToParent`.

If you apply these changes, your code will then look like this:

```
try
{
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    // make the Task throw an exception
    MessageBox.Show("This is T1");
  });
  await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    MessageBox.Show("This is Continuation");
  });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Actually I've read your article, and your blog before posting this. Really good stuff, but a bit advanced for a newby like me in await/async. So, according to your solution I can replicate the behavior of ContinueWith by placing two Task.Run in a Row and forget about creation of task and Task.start. If yes when your solution seems really elegant.

Comment: `Task.Run` replaces the `Task` constructor and `Task.Start`. `await` replaces `ContinueWith`. I have an [intro to `async`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post that you may find helpful.

Comment: Will certainly check it out. Thanks